# Moment.js: Cannot read property 'defineLocale' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I think this is an error concerning the inclusion of Moment.js but I'm not entirely sure. I get a few errors, although I beleive they are entirely the result of the first. In full the first error is:

```
af.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defineLocale' of undefined
    at af.js:13
    at af.js:9
    at af.js:10
```

`af.js` is the Moment.js local configuration file, the line to which this error points is line 13 which is as shown:

```
var af = moment.defineLocale('af', {
```

Here is how I include it in my `<head>` tag (it is the penultimate `<script>` tag):

```
<head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MatthewLoveday/mq/master/mathquill.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MatthewLoveday/mq/0c20cf96/mathquill.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/locale/af.js"></script>

    <script>var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);</script>

    <title>Maths Site</title>
</head>
```

I'm only using it in conjunction with Chart.js, but to show all my usage of Chart.js I beleive would be a bit excessive for this question.

Comment: You haven’t included `moment.js` itself.

Comment: @Xufox I just followed the instructions on their site (https://momentjs.com/docs/) which says to use (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js), if I'm not including it, how do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js there are several links to Moment *locales*. Only the bottom four links are different: those are the regular `moment.js` source and the `moment-with-locales.js`, both in a minified and a regular version each.

You’ve picked the Afrikaans locale (the first source in the list), which assumes `moment-with-locales.js` to be loaded already. However, it’s very likely that you just needed the regular `moment.js` (minified). So replace

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/locale/af.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/mome‌​nt.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was just lazy.